# Manter Tab Selecionada após PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estou tentando manter a tab selecionada, após o postback, estou tentando fazer dessa forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#myTabs").tabs({
                activate: function () {
                    var selectedTab = $('#myTabs').tabs('option', 'active');
                    $("#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
                },
                active: document.getElementById('<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').value
            });
        });
    </script>


<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />
```

Além de mudar o design das tabs, ainda não funciona. Já fiz de várias formas e nenhuma funciona, utilizo bootstrap na página. 
Também tentei essa função, que também não funcionou:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        prm.add_endRequest(function () {

            // Mantém ativa as mesmas tabs do último postBack
            var tabAtivaIndex = $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val();
            $("#myTabs").tabs({ selected: tabAtivaIndex });

        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= fragment1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val("0");
            });
            $('#<%= fragment2.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val("1");
            });
            $('#<%= fragment3.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val("2");
            });
            $('#<%= fragment4.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val("3");
            });
            $('#<%= fragment5.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val("4");
            });
            $('#<%= fragment6.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val("5");
            });
            $('#<%= fragment7.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val("6");
            });
            $('#<%= fragment8.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>').val("7");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Veja este link, talvez resolva seu problema [twitter bootstrap 3 setting active tab in js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417905/twitter-bootstrap-3-setting-active-tab-in-js-not-working)

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu, estou pesquisando, pra ver se encontro algo que possa me ajudar. Obrigado.